# Aptana Studio: treats .py as html

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I am using Aptana Studio 3 to develop an application in python+django. But for some reason Aptana Studio treats one of my .py file as html.

So, for that file I have no syntax highlighting, moreover when I try to comment code using Ctrl + '/', it wraps the code with html comment tags `<!-- -->` instead of python comment tags and it also throws a warning message at the end saying: "should insert missing 'title' element". All of this suggesting that Aptana is expecting a html file despite .py extension.

Important: I manually created  this file using `<Package Name>(right click) > New > File`, all my other .py files are auto generated when I created the project and they are working as expected. The file compiles well however.

Any clue, what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, create a new .py file using `<Package Name>(right click) > New > PyDev Module`. Basically create `New PyDev Module` doesn't matter how.

Earlier I used `New File` instead of `New PyDev Module`, which led to Aptana treating it as regular file (html probably) despite its .py extension.